# Trace map from $\Bbb Q\Bbb(\zeta_r)$ to $\Bbb Q\Bbb.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-fields, field-trace

I am interested in knowing how to get values of $Tr_r(a)$.

Where $Tr_r$ is trace map from $\Bbb Q\Bbb(\zeta_r)$ to $\mathbb Q\mathbb,$ and $\zeta_r$ are some specific complex roots of unit.

Not really familiar to what a "trace map" is.

Comment: the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace) is the sum of the conjugates of $a$ (which are obtained from $a$ by replacing one primitive complex root of unity with another)

Comment: are you familiar with [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm)?  that's another function from $\mathbb Q(\zeta_r)$ to $\mathbb Q$, but it's the *product* of conjugates

Comment: Suppose $K/F$ is a finite field extension. Any element $x \in K$ defines an $F$-linear map $l_{x} \colon K \to K$ given by multiplication by $x$. The trace map $\mathrm{Tr}_{K/F} \colon K \to F$ sends an element $x$ to the trace of the associated linear map $l_{x}$. When $K/F$ is a Galois extension, one may show that this definition coincides with the one given by J. W. Tanner above.

Comment: @AlexWertheim:  and the norm map N$_{K/F}$ sends $x$ to the determinant of $l_x$, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: indeed!

Comment: Thanks J.W.Tanner and Alex Wertheim for quick and straight answers. To be sure I correctly understood: If map is from $\Bbb Q\Bbb(e^{2\pi i/3})$ to $\Bbb Q\Bbb.$ Then $Tr(\frac{3\zeta}{1-\zeta})=\frac{3\zeta^0}{1-\zeta^0}+\frac{3\zeta^1}{1-\zeta^1}+\frac{3\zeta^2}{1-\zeta^2}$. Isn't it?

Comment: @24th_moonshine:  leave out the term with $\zeta^0$.  $\;\zeta^1$ has only one conjugate, namely, $\zeta^2$.